# jsf view not updating backing bean list property after modification

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a strange problem that I could not resolve. I have two entities, `Dept` and `Division`. A `Dept` must belong to a `Division`. Thus, there is a list of `depts` for each `Division`. I also have two views, `dept.xhtml` and `division.xhtml` to manage the two entities (CRUD Operations). Both views are backed by `DeptManager` and `DivManager`, which are both ViewScoped.

There is a DELETE button on `division.xhtml`, which is to be disabled when the selected `Division` has some `Dept` entities attached to it. When I go to `dept.xhtml` and change the `Division` assigned to a particular `Dept`, the Dept table on `dept.xhtml` is updated correctly. However, when I navigate to `division.xhtml`, the Division table does not capture the update. The value in the column showing the number of Depts for the recently-modified Division retains previous values before the modification. This affects the DELETE button on `division.xhtml`, which might be disabled when it shouldnt be. I have to close the browser and re-open it before the update is captured. I believe this should not be because my navigation causes a new view to be created each time and I have verified that by some print-outs. Here are my codes:

`dept.xhtml`

```
<h:body>
        <ui:composition template="adminTemplate.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="content">
                <h:form id="form">
                    <p:dataTable id="dtable" value="#{deptManager.orderedDepts}" var="dept" 
                                 selectionMode="single" selection="#{deptManager.dept}" rowIndexVar="index"  
                                 rowKey="#{dept.deptCode}" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="270">
                        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{deptManager.onRowSelect}" update=":form:fields"  />

                        <f:facet name="header">List of Departments</f:facet>
                        <p:column headerText="S/No">#{index+1}</p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Department Code" sortBy="deptCode">#{dept.deptCode}</p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Department Name" sortBy="description" >#{dept.description}</p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Division" sortBy="description" >#{dept.divCode.description}</p:column>
                        <f:facet name="footer">Number of Departments #{deptManager.count}</f:facet>
                    </p:dataTable>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <p:panel  header="Create/Modify Dept" toggleable="true" toggleOrientation="vertical">
                        <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="fields">
                            <p:outputLabel value="Department Code:"/> <p:inputText value="#{deptManager.dept.deptCode}" disabled="true" />
                            <p:outputLabel value="Department Description:"/> <p:inputText value="#{deptManager.dept.description}" />                  
                            <p:outputLabel value="Department Division"/> 
                            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{deptManager.dept.divCode}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select.." noSelectionOption="true" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{divManager.orderedDivs}" itemLabel="#{division.description}" var="division" itemValue="#{division}" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>  
                        </p:panelGrid>
                        <p:commandButton ajax="true" actionListener="#{deptManager.createNew}" value="NEW" update="@form" />
                        <p:commandButton ajax="true" actionListener="#{deptManager.deleteDept}" value="DELETE" update="@form" />
                        <p:commandButton ajax="true" actionListener="#{deptManager.saveDept}" value="SAVE" update="@form"  />
                    </p:panel>  

                </h:form>                                
            </ui:define>            
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
```

`DeptManager`

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class DeptManager implements Serializable{  
    @EJB
    private DeptFacade service;   

    private Dept dept;
    private List<Dept> depts;

    @Inject
    private DivManager divManager;

    public DeptManager() {

    }

    public DivManager getDivManager() {
        return divManager;
    }

    public void setDivManager(DivManager divManager) {
        this.divManager = divManager;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void Init(){
        dept = new Dept();
        updateList();
    }

    public void setService(DeptFacade service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public Dept getDept() {
        if(dept == null){
            dept = new Dept();
        }
        return dept;
    }

    public void updateList(){
        depts = service.findOrderedAll("Dept", "deptCode");
    }    

    public void setDept(Dept dept) {
        this.dept = dept;
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return service.count();
    }

    public List<Dept> getDepts(){
        return service.findAll();
    }

    public List<Dept> getOrderedDepts(){
        return depts;
    }

    public String createNew(){
        dept = new Dept();
        dept.setDeptCode("");
        dept.setDivCode(null);
        dept.setDescription("");
        return "";
    }

    public String saveDept(){
        //code to create or edit Dept
        updateList();
        divManager.updateList();
        return "dept.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public String deleteDept(){
        if (dept.getDeptCode() == null || dept.getDeptCode().isEmpty()){
            return "dept";
        }
        service.remove(dept);
        dept = new Dept();
        updateList();
        divManager.updateList();
        return "dept";
    }

    public String onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {  
        dept = (Dept) event.getObject();
        return "";
    } 

    public String navigate(String page){
        return page;
    }

}
```

`division.xhtml`

```
<h:body>
        <ui:composition template="adminTemplate.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="content">
                <h:form id="form">
                    <p:dataTable id="dtable" value="#{divManager.orderedDivs}" var="division" 
                                 selectionMode="single" selection="#{divManager.division}" rowIndexVar="index"  
                                 rowKey="#{division.divCode}" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="300">
                        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{divManager.onRowSelect}" update=":form:fields"  />

                        <f:facet name="header">List of Divisions</f:facet>
                        <p:column headerText="S/No">#{index+1}</p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Division Code" sortBy="divCode">#{division.divCode}</p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Division Name" sortBy="description" >#{division.description}</p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="No Of Depts"  >#{division.invDeptList.size()}</p:column>
                        <f:facet name="footer">Number of Divisions: #{divManager.count}</f:facet>
                    </p:dataTable>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <p:panel id="fields" header="Create/Modify Division" toggleable="true" toggleOrientation="vertical">
                        <p:panelGrid columns="2" >
                            <p:outputLabel value="Division Code:"/> <p:inputText value="#{divManager.division.divCode}" disabled="true" />
                            <p:outputLabel value="Division Description:"/> <p:inputText value="#{divManager.division.description}" />                  
                        </p:panelGrid>
                        <p:commandButton ajax="true" actionListener="#{divManager.createNew}" value="NEW" update="@form" />
                        <p:commandButton ajax="true" actionListener="#{divManager.deleteDiv}" disabled="#{divManager.division.deptList.size() > 0}" value="DELETE" update="@form" />
                        <p:commandButton ajax="true" actionListener="#{divManager.saveDiv}" value="SAVE" update="@form"  />
                    </p:panel>  

                </h:form>                                
            </ui:define>            
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
```

`DivisionManager`

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class DivManager implements Serializable{

    @EJB
    private DivFacade service;

    private Div division;   
    private ArrayList<Div> divisions;  
    private boolean newInstance;

    public DivManager() {

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void Init(){
        newInstance = true;
        division = new Div();
        divisions = new ArrayList<Div>();
        updateList();
        System.out.println("DivManager bean "+this.toString()+" was created");
    }

    public Div getDivision() {
        if(division == null){
            division = new Div();
        }
        return division;
    }

    public void setService(DivFacade service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void updateList(){
        divisions.clear();
        divisions.addAll(service.findOrderedAll("Div", "divCode"));
        // Also tried: divisions = service.findOrderedAll("Div", "divCode"); same result
    }    

    public void setDivision(Div div) {
        this.division = div;
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return service.count();
    }

    public List<Div> getDivisions(){
        return service.findAll();
    }

    public List<Div> getOrderedDivs(){
        if(newInstance){
            updateList();
            newInstance = false;
        }
        return divisions;
    }

    public String createNew(){
        division = new Div();
        division.setDivCode("");        
        division.setDescription("");
        return null;
    }

    public String saveDiv(){
        //code to modify or create Division
        updateList();
        return "division.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public String deleteDiv(){
        if (division.getDivCode() == null || division.getDivCode().isEmpty()){
            return null;
        }
        service.remove(division);
        division = new Div();
        updateList();        
        return null;
    }

    public String onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {  
        division = (Div) event.getObject();
        return null;
    } 

    public String navigate(String page){
        return page;
    }

}
```

From my observation, it looks as if the field `divisions` is cached and new instances of viewScoped bean `DivManager` get the same list when `updateList()` is called, unless the session is invalidated. Thus the same List of Divisions in the cache is returned instead of calling the `find` method on the `Session` Bean `service`.

Any idea on what could be causing this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of troubleshooting, I discovered that the `EntityManager` used by the `Stateless Session Bean` keeps a cache of `Entities` retrieved from the database. Therefore, as long as the same `Session Bean` is assigned to the backing bean of a `View` fetching those `Entities` will always return the cached copy, which might not be up-to-date.

To solve the problem, I made use of boolean field `newInstance` in my backing bean. This field is checked whenever there is a call to fetch the list of `Entities`. If `newInstance` is true, I loop through all the entities and refresh them from the database.This way, as long as the `View` being visited is new (which is verified by checking if the `Viewscoped` backing bean is new), calling `updateList` will cause the `Entities` in the list to be refreshed. Here is the modified code:

```
@DivManager
public void updateList(){
    service.refreshList(divisions);
}
```

And in the `SSB` service, I have the method:

```
public void refreshList(List<Div> divisions){
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    for(Div divison : divisions){
        division = em.find(Div.class, division.getDivCode());
        em.refresh(division);
    }
}
```

Although this solved the problem, I envisage performance issue if the number of records is large. If there is a way to monitor only the entities that have been modified since the last call to `refreshList()` and refresh only those, it will be better. I am thinking about implementing such a solution.

Hope this will help someone.